# Cabeçalho com várias linhas jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Preciso gerar pdf a partir de uma table, só que o meu cabeçalho possui várias linhas e o meu código está sobrepondo essas linhas, segue imagem: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que cada tr fique em uma linha diferente, como seria possível?

```
var startColPosition=defaults.pdfLeftMargin;
$(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {
     $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){                  
                 if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                       var colPosition = startColPosition+ (index * 50);                                    
                       doc.text(colPosition,20, parseString($(this)));
                  }
            }
      });                                   
});
```

Comment: recomendo a utilização do plugin jsPDF-AutoTable que trata da impressão de tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

Olá fazer isso assim é mais complexo, por isso recomendo a utilização do plugin jsPDF-AutoTable que trata da impressão de tabelas de forma simples. Veja aqui no Git [jspdf & auto table](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)

Comment: no meu projeto eu dou a opção de download através de um botão, dessa forma: <a href="#" onClick ="$('#empenho_solicitante').tableExport({type:'pdf', escape:'false'});"><img src='../../imagens/icons/pdf.png' width="24"/> PDF</a> -- como eu faria algo do tipo utilizando o autoTable? vc poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @V.Avancini vê este exemplo aqui https://jsfiddle.net/sereno/p5pcLqz2/